# Poodle Vulnerability in Centos 5

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, centos, poodle-attack

I am running centos 5.7 with the openssl-0.9.8e-22.el5_11 and it's affected by poodle vulnerability. So to address this I have upgraded my openssl version to openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.

I have confirmed like the fix for poodle vulnerability is available in the above version by using changelog.

```
[root]# rpm -qa --changelog openssl | grep CVE
- add support for fallback SCSV to partially mitigate CVE-2014-3566
- fix CVE-2014-0221 - recursion in DTLS code leading to DoS
- fix CVE-2014-3505 - doublefree in DTLS packet processing
- fix CVE-2014-3506 - avoid memory exhaustion in DTLS
- fix CVE-2014-3508 - fix OID handling to avoid information leak
```

But however, still my system is using SSLv3 as per the below test.

```
[root]# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 10.197.65.190

Starting Nmap 5.51
Nmap scan report for 10.197.65.190
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
PORT STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
| SSLv3
| Ciphers (
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
| Compressors (1)
| uncompressed
| TLSv1.0
| Ciphers (
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
| TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
| TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
| Compressors (1)
|_ uncompressed
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.28 seconds

I am getting little bit confused here.Whether really poodle vulnerability is fixed in openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.

Any help on this will be highly appreciatable.

Comment: *"Any help on this will be highly appreciated"* - what, exactly, is the question? Stack Overflow is a programming and development Q&A site. And I can't figure out what the programming question is here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No upgrade for openssl will fix POODLE, because POODLE is a design flaw in SSL 3.0 and not a bug in OpenSSL. All the upgrade does is to add an option which might be used be servers to detect protocol downgrade attempts of the client.

The real fix is to disable SSL 3.0 in all applications which use the OpenSSL library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in internet I found that openssl 0.9.8zc contains the fix for this issue. Is it true?  or even 0.9.8zc also will also only prevent the downgrade attempts by MITM from client

Comment: Again, there is no fix because it is a design problem, that is SSL 3.0 is unfixable broken. The fallback SCSV option only helps to detect downgrade attacks, but only if client and server support this option. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566 for more detailed information.

Comment: http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-3568  As per the above link the openssl is build with no-sslv3 option to disable the sslv3 support from the server.   can you please clarify this too.Sorry for keep on asking the same same question.

Comment: This link only says that OpenSSL did not properly enforce the -no-ssl3 build option. This is an option one can use but don't need to use when building OpenSSL. The default is to build with SSL3.0 support. This link makes no statement about how the OpenSSL rpm you use was built and the change description you cite says also nothing about disabling support for SSL 3.0.

Comment: It is possible to mitigate POODLE without disabling SSLv3 as POODLE affects only CBC cipher suites. You can keep SSLv3 using RC4 ciphers, but it has its weaknesses too...